# TextBox не выводит значение, хотя строка получена

Tags: c#, winforms, строки, textbox

```
Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой.
```

В Windows Form создал текстбокс с именем `tbCommandName1` . Далее при клике на кнопку я получаю значение с вебсайта, которое я затем передаю в метод `PrintName`. Но далее значение не выводится в мою форму. Почему эта строка не срабатывает правильно `tbCommandName1.Text = Name;` ?
Заранее спасибо на потраченное на меня время.

```
  private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ID = tbGetID.Text;
            Second.StartBrowser(Second.GetDriver(), ID);
        }

        public void PrintName(string Command1Name)
        {
            string Name = Command1Name;
            tbCommandName1.Text = Name; //не выводит значение в форму
        }
    }
    public class Second
    {
        private static ChromeDriver driver = null;
        public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
        {
            if (driver == null)
            {
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
            }
            return driver;
        }

        public static void StartBrowser(ChromeDriver driver, string ID)
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("my url" + ID);
            GetInfo();    
        }



        public static void GetInfo()   
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            string CommandName1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[1]")).Text;
            Favorit favorit = new Favorit();
            favorit.PrintName(CommandName1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаете новую форму, вместо того, чтобы использовать ту, которая уже существует на экране.

```
...
Second.StartBrowser(Second.GetDriver(), ID, this);
...

public class Second
{
    private static ChromeDriver driver = null;
    public static ChromeDriver GetDriver()
    {
        if (driver == null)
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public static void StartBrowser(ChromeDriver driver, string ID, Favorit aForm)
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("my url" + ID);
        GetInfo(aForm);    
    }



    public static void GetInfo(Favorit aForm)   
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        string CommandName1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='react-root']/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/header/div[2]/span[1]")).Text;
        aForm.PrintName(CommandName1);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое за быстрый ответ! Вы просто ГУРУ!

Comment: @TheVee На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: Еще небольшой вопрос. Я добавил конструкцию do-while, почему значения не отображатся в реальном времени? Хочу смотреть в приложении динамические значения с сайта. Заранее спасибо.